# DC Motor inertia voltage drop

Tags: dc-motor, simulation, spice, ltspice, modeling

following a tutorial on the web I created in LTSpice a DC motor model, but I have a question about the results, the model is:

[image: LTSpiceModel]

and this is the spice netlist:

```
V_MOTOR N001 0 PULSE(0 10 0.05 1u 1u 1 10 1)
R_MOTOR N001 N002 {R_M}
H_TORQUE H_TORQUE_PROBE 0 V_SENSE_1 {Kt}
R_Friction H_TORQUE_PROBE V_SEEN_BY_L_INERTIA {R_F}
V_SENSE_1 N004 N003 0
V_SENSE_2 N005 0 0
H_BE N003 0 V_SENSE_2 {K_bemf}
L_MOTOR N002 N004 {L_M}
L_INERTIA V_SEEN_BY_L_INERTIA N005 {L_I}
.tran 2
.PARAM R_M 0.5
.PARAM L_M 1.5m
.PARAM L_I 0.25m
.PARAM Kt 0.05
.PARAM R_F 0.0001
.PARAM K_bemf 0.05
.backanno
.end
```

The results are:

[image: LTSpiceGraph]

My question is: why V(V_SEEN_BY_L_INERTIA), representing inertia of the motor is not 0 at steady rate? As far as I know voltage across an inductor is given by L*d(i)/d(t) so as you can see by the green line when current is (almost) constant there should be no voltage drop across inductor! 
Obviously this is a result we expect considering that at steady rate the motor has an inertia, but I cannot understand how it is possible being no current change.

Thanks,
Vincenzo

Comment: Where is the tutorial?

Comment: Looking at your netlist, you have one node labeled `V_SEEN_BY_L2` and another node labeled `V_SEEN_BY_L_INERTIA`. It looks like these are supposed to be the same node. Although I can't explain why you get any voltage on the latter node at all.

Comment: Sorry I've changed the name to reflect the image content, going to edit it.

Comment: @DaveTweed http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/dc_motor_model/DCmotor_model.htm and http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/application-notes-technical-guides/application-bulletins/ab-025-using-spice-to-model-dc-motors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understood the problem: 
at what it seems Spice, if no argument is given, set a series resistance of 1 mOhm with the inductor, if a value of 0 is set for inductors series resistence the voltage across the inductor drops to 0 as desired.

Source: http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/L_Inductor.htm